# Trouble getting data into an inner class

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I'm trying to write a program that is just a little beyond my abilities.The program is supposed to retrieve GPS data and display it on a nice page of graphics.  I can access the GPS data fine, by implementing the necessary listener interfaces.  I can display nice graphics using a sophisticated program structure employing a SurfaceView.  But when I try to pull these two functionalites (incoming data and graphics) together things fall apart.

The graphics structure of the program is, in schematic form:

Activity implements several gpsStatus/Location interfaces

```
Anonymous inner class Panel extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
        onDraw() which does the drawing

        inner (instance) class Thread
            run() which does the canvas locking and calls onDraw()
```

I hope that makes sense. I got this structure from the Droidnova site, the 2D graphics tutorial.  The graphics are drawn in the separate thread.  I've been able to get very nice smooth graphics out of this.

The class "Panel," the one which extends SurfaceView is created in the onCreate of the Activity, like this: setContentView(new Panel(this));  The inner class is created as an instance, i.e. Thread thread=new Thread() by the Panel's constructor.

My data from the GPS chip comes in via methods in the Activity.  The problem is, how do I get these objects inside the "Panel" and into the onDraw()?  From within the onDraw() the objects in the Activity (my GPS data) are inaccessible.

I've tried creating the SurfaceView as an instance, I've tried moving the SurfaceView out so it's a separate class (with the thread still inside).  I've tried implementing the interfaces in the Panel  These always crash, with debug data I can't fathom.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Those indecipherable debug messages might actually help, can you post them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that if you wrapped your GPS data into a class foo, and pass a reference to an instance of foo into a constructor on Panel, you should have all you need.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I figured there was something obvious like that...I'm not particularly experienced and it didn't occur to me that you can overload a constructor that way (i.e. add to the parameters you feed it)...I'll try that.

Comment: This seems to be working!  I created a class gpsDataHolder, and have holder.setData() in the outer Activity (where the gps callbacks are) and holder.getData() in the onDraw in the inner SurfaceView, and have been able to "bridge the gulf" into the anonymous inner class.  Thank you very much again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner class is declared inside the Activity class (listening to the gps data), then the inner class should be able to access the member variables of the Activity class.
It is not very OO, but it should work.

Comment: The Panel (inner drawing class) is anonymous in the template I'm using, its created in the Activity by setContentView(new Panel(this)).

Comment: I've tried Panel myPanel=new Panel and setContentView(myPanel(this)), but I'm pretty sure that crashed too.